# Same file producing different data encoded output

Tags: html, bash, character-encoding, webstorm

I have a html file which has Japanese characters.

On My mac, if I go to finder and double click it, opens in browser, looks fine as follows.

> カード申し込み

This is path when hitting the file via finder:

```
file:///Users/uname/projects/assets/my-project/y.html
```

But If I stay in `WebStorm`, and open it from there, it opens in following path and ends up looking malformed as follows.

> ã‚«ãƒ¼ãƒ‰ç”³ã—è¾¼ã¿

This is path from WebStorm:

```
http://localhost:63342/my-project/assets/y.html?_ijt=ntsb1tp0fggkxtkqk86vg3foma&_ij_reload=RELOAD_ON_SAVE
```

Why? It is the same file. It seems environment related.

When I deploy my code, the same issue observed in WebStorm, is seen when deployed too.

Minimised the html file down to contain only the following.

If you save the following as a html file and run on your machine via WebStorm, believe you would see the same issue too.

```
<label tabindex="0">カード申し込み</label>
```

What is the issue, how to resolve this?

Is there anything I could do via a Shell script to get the html file to resolve the encoding issue.

At present, the file is being saved as follows using `curl` where html data is pulled from an endpoint.

```
curl -o "assets/y.html" "https://example.com/endpoint"
```

Comment: Webstorm is serving the file using the wrong `Content-Type` header, indicating the wrong encoding to the browser. Where that can be configured specifically I don’t know.

Comment: 1) Please share the actual file (zip it first) via Google Drive or alike service. Maybe it's about BOM bytes, or the missing/wrong HTML encoding attribute. 2) In WebStorm, you can set file encodings at `Settings/Preferences  | Editor | File Encodings` (may require restart in some cases, at least it was in the past). 3) *"This is path from WebStorm:"* In your browser, open the Network tab of the Dev Tools and check what encoding is used for that file/URL.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'カード申し込み'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252', errors='ignore')` returns `'ã‚«ãƒ¼ãƒ‰ç”³ã—è¾¼ã¿'`…